# Android Studio Back Button issue

Tags: java, android-studio

EDITED**

I've been trying to implement a back button for my ToDoList project.What I'm trying to make it do is on pressing the back button on my phone while the user is typing something in the Editable field which is in the second_layout(Editable activity),he could go back to the MainActivity without passing data,therefore the first_layout.I already have a method called saveClick() which basically passes the text input from the Editable field which is in second_layout back to MainActivity(first_layout).

This is the method itself.

```
     public void saveClick(View view) {
     String messageString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_message)).getText().toString();
    if (messageString.equals("")) {
    }
    else {
   Intent intent=new Intent();
   intent.putExtra(IntentCode.INTENT_MESSAGE_CODE,messageString);
   setResult(IntentCode.INTENT_RESULT_CODE,intent);
   finish();
    }
```

And this is the onActivityResult

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == IntentCode.INTENT_RESULT_CODE)
    messageString = data.getStringExtra(IntentCode.INTENT_MESSAGE_CODE);
    toDoList.add(messageString);
    theAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to open the `BackPress` Activity when a user hits BACK on your `MainActivity`.

First of all, inside your `onBackPressed()` implementation, the call to `super.onBackPressed()` will tell the OS to simply go back to the previous Activity in the Activity Stack (or close the application if the stack is empty). If you don't want that to happen, then remove that line.

Secondly, your `Intent` object is not correct. If the Activity you want to open is called `BackPressActivity`, then you should have the following code:

```
Intent backPressIntent = new Intent(this, BackPressActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(backPressIntent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

But again, I don't recommend having such a flow because think about what would happen when the user presses BACK inside `BackPressActivity`? It'll go back to `MainActivity`, then pressing BACK will take the user to `BackPressActivity` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

By default, `super.onBackPressed()` finish current Activity.

As the intent, First Activity attempt to start another Activity if user click the back Button, and receive second Activity's result through `onActivityResult()`.

So, when the second Activity finished with result, first Activity should be alive to catch the result.

As result, we should not close current Activity which `super.onBackPressed()` provide. Just remove the line and it should be done.

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backPressed=new Intent();
    backPressed.setClass(MainActivity.this,Editable.class);
    startActivityForResult(backPressed,IntentCode.INTENT_BACK_PRESSED);
 }
```

But it would be a problem when we need to quite the FirstActivity. Better to do like this.

```
@Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    if(Exit condition...){
        super.onBackPressed();        
    } else {
        Intent backPressed=new Intent();
        backPressed.setClass(MainActivity.this,Editable.class);
        startActivityForResult(backPressed,IntentCode.INTENT_BACK_PRESSED);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Intent backPressed = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Editable.class);
startActivity(backPressed);
```

Instead of

```
Intent backPressed=new Intent(); backPressed.setClass(MainActivity.this,Editable.class); startActivityForResult(backPressed,IntentCode.INTENT_BACK_PRESSED); }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try simply using this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       Intent backPressed = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Editable.class);
       startActivity(backPressed);
    }
```